# Meaning of ScopeGroupId in custom theme liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

When exactly is `scopeGroupId` set in Liferay 6? Is there any way I can change it while adding my portlets dynamically to the custom theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupId` is typically the current site that is displayed and *typically* the same as `scopeGroupId`. However, content in Liferay can be "subscoped" to individual pages. You can find this in the configuration screen of several portlets. Thus, the data is not associated directly with the site (aka group), but with a subscope of that site. Hence scopeGroupId.

Typically the theme doesn't change it willingly, but it's the content that is currently being shown that passes the current scope into the theme.

Comment: I have created 2 sites & created some content in respective site scope.Each site has 1 user assigned.When I try to login with any user I am fetching its site id and getting all the contents under that site scope. This works fine,but what I am seeing is ,Scope group id is always passed incorrectly while adding the content dynamically in portal_normal.vm of my custom theme.Instead of using current site id its using site id of default liferay site and not able to locate the content in database with that article id and site id combination.I have posted separate question for this on SO.